# How to make a simple predict by tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am learning Tensorflow, so I try to make some data to 'predict'. But it seems not correct...Loss is too high and accuracy is 0.
Like this
[image: I tryed to compare y and y_true]

I don't know where is my mistakes...

Comment: 1. `metrics=[accuracy]`. accuracy is a metric for classification. But you have a regression. So use something else like mean_squared_error. 2. You don't have to use `relu` activation function. So remove it. It makes the model a little more better.

Comment: And you are training model with `y` and `y_true`? What does it mean? I think you have made a mistake in `model.fit(y,y_true)`. You  should set it like `model.fit(x,y_true)`.

Comment: At the beginning, I wanted to use **y = x^2 + ep** . But I don't know how to expression it in Dense. So I simplified this, and ues **y** directly.

Comment: Do I need to change my code like 
model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Dense(units=1, input_shape=(None,1)),
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='mean_squared_error',
              metrics=['mean_squared_error'])

Answer (score 0):

Your model is clearly regression and you are using `MSE` for loss. For last (and only) layer activation you have two options - `sigmoid` which is regression nonlinear function or `linear` wich more fits your linear problem.

Remember that this model will look like this:

```
activation(ax + b)
```

In current configuration (`model.fit(y, y_true)`) your model would learn to parameters like this:

```
a = 1
b = -epsilon
```

and because `epsilon` is random number then parameter `b` would be also random number between 0 and 0.1.